# Can't access custom profile properties from web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I have the following two profile properties in my web.config file between the System.Web tags:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
<profile>
  <properties>
    <add name="CustomerName" allowAnonymous="true"/>
    <add name="CustomerID" allowAnonymous="true"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

When I try to access the Profile.CustomerName or Profile.CustomerID from an aspx.cs file, it doesn't show up.  I thought when you create a custom profile property, it automatically updates the aspnetdb with the new properties.  Profile doesn't show up in intellisense as well.

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs if you are creating a Web Application. Web Apps, unlike Websites, don't generate the ProfileCommon class.
You could either follow this method:
http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/Migration2/Migration2.aspx
(Appendix 2)

I haven't personally used the above assembly, so someone else might give some advice on that.
However, you could also try:

```
Object customerName = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("CustomerName")
```

You won't get intellisense with this method, but as long as you know the property name, it can be accessed like that.

Comment: Instead of inheriting ProfileBase and creating own class, I guess the method you had provided is the simplest way. You additionally set the value of the property using - HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("CustomerName", "MyCustomer")

Answer (score 0):

Specify properties in web.config file as follows : -
[image: ProfilePropertyWeb.config]

Now, write the following code : -

[image: Code Behind Profile Properties]

Compile and run the code. You will get following output: -

[image: Output]